# A alternative to cassandra for Small Projects on low end hardware?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, couchdb, high-availability

I'm preparing a infrastructure for a new project:

- data center 1, server and db
- dc 2, server and db
- dc 3, server and db
- dc x

(all quite low end servers, to reduce starting costs, so latency may be high)

The db's should form a cluster spanning the dc's. Consistency is not so important, loosing a few records when something goes down is not a problem or that dc1 db sees different data compared to dc2 db for a few seconds.

What is important is the automatic failover and correct automatic behavior when a dc comes up again.

Cassandra does all this and more, but i suspect it is a bit overkill, cause my dataset is small and my hardware isn't very good. I would only be using cassandra because of the high availability features.

Is there a alternative to cassandra which is better suited for low end/small projects but that still offers all the high availability features including replication across dc's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know enough about your application to know whether it would be the best choice, but I can tell you that Cassandra can be tuned to run in as little as a few hundred MB of RAM or less quite easily if your dataset is small.

Comment: Indeed, after looking at the configuration options it seems to be quite flexible in addition you can plugin your own strategies in several places. I'll get a few cassandra nodes running on virtualbox and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Two DBs you can check are couchbase (http://www.couchbase.com/) and riak (http://basho.com/riak/). Both have decent cross-dc features.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Rotem. Took a peek at riak before and it is quite expensive when you want the more advanced features. I'm a bit worried that a product like couchbase will also exclude the advanced features from the open source version. Also took a look at bigcouch, but that one is not being developed cause of integration with couchdb (no release yet) and it always takes a long time until such a product is matured. Any more suggestions are of course welcome ;-)

Comment: I think couchbase are not differentiating the enterprise product by features but by support. see here - http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/editions. Another option is couchDB, I'm not very familiar with it's replication features but I see there's a master-master replication so maybe it will do - http://couchdb.apache.org/

Comment: This worries me quite a bit "Fixes are eventually integrated with the open-source and Community Edition releases". Couchdb can become interesting when bigcouch is integrated and matured, at this point there isn't a first release yet.